# ReferenceError: queueMicrotask is not defined at RedisSocket.cork

Tags: node.js, express, redis, centos7, socket.io-redis

I'm running Node JS with express using socket.io to connect redis server. Starting the application on command line works perfectly but when i register the application with Application Manager via CPanel and i tried opening the url on browser the following error

```
App 18072 output: ReferenceError: queueMicrotask is not defined
App 18072 output:     at RedisSocket.cork (/home/mypayve/socket.mypayve.com/node_modules/@node-redis/client/dist/lib/$
App 18072 output:     at Commander._RedisClient_tick (/home/mypayve/socket.mypayve.com/node_modules/@node-redis/clien$
App 18072 output:     at RedisSocket.socketInitiator (/home/mypayve/socket.mypayve.com/node_modules/@node-redis/clien$
App 18072 output:     at RedisSocket._RedisSocket_connect (/home/mypayve/socket.mypayve.com/node_modules/@node-redis/$
App 18072 output:     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ E 2022-03-06 13:16:08.7395 17714/Tf age/Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:221 ]: Could not spawn process for application /$
  Error ID: b1103f38
  Error details saved to: /var/run/ea-ruby27-passenger/passenger-error-CJDgDh.html

[ E 2022-03-06 13:16:08.7468 17714/T5 age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:283 ]: [Client 1-1] Cannot checkout session bec$
[ E 2022-03-06 13:16:08.7477 17714/Ta age/Cor/Con/CheckoutSession.cpp:283 ]: [Client 2-1] Cannot checkout session bec$
```

get's logged to `/var/log/apache2/error_log`
I search the internet for solution but to no luck i event found this [Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296700/queuemicrotask-error-when-connecting-node-redis-with-typescript) and applied the steps mentioned but yet nothing worked!

Please i need help! What could be causing this error?

Answer (score -1):

[queueMicrotask](https://nodejs.org/api/globals.html#queuemicrotaskcallback) was only added to NodeJS from version 11.0.0. I suggest you check your Node version and upgrade if it's <=10